# Autowiring objects with constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to get an object from spring factory which has a constructor argument and the value of which is specified at run time. How do I do this. This worked well if I don't have any constructor.

```
@Service
public class PortService implements Runnable {

@Autowired
LeaveProcessor leaveProcessor;

private Socket socket;

public PortService(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    PrintWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        String message = reader.readLine();
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer.println(leaveProcessor.process(message));
        writer.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Edit - Without constructor I can make it work by directly accessing Autowireed object leaveProcessor.

Socket : This is loaded from factory:

```
public void start() {

    try {
        ServerSocket mobCom = new ServerSocket(9846);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = mobCom.accept();
            PortService portService = new PortService(socket);
            executorService.submit(portService);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: who is passing `socket`

Comment: Look at @Configurable, that will need aspectj load time weaving.  The best option it to create a Factory class that is managed by spring and then use it to create your objects.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a factory bean

```
public class PortServiceFactory implements FactoryBean<PortService> {
     PortService getObject() {
         Socket socket;
         // Code to initialize the socket
         return new PortService(socket);
     }
     // FactoryBean interface requires a couple of other methods,
     // implement those
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the constructor argument from your context.xml file itself.

```
    <bean id="theBeanID" class="your.package.PortService" >
       <constructor-arg ref="socketBeanID"  />  
     </bean>

    <bean id="socketBeanID" class="your.package.Socket" />
```

I don't know how you are creating the Socket object but it must be passed to the constructor inside your xml context file itself.

If you can avoid using constructor, please autowire the Socket class itself.

```
@Autowired
private Socket socket;
```

OR, instantiate it in your class PortService itself using **new** keyword.

OR, use some static factory method which create the Socket object if required.